# Web Service method name is not valid c# json ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am making a email contact form with a ajax post on a umbraco site, I am halway thru it and was just testing the ajax part and I get a "Web Service method name is not valid" error when it runs.

I have a booking.cs in app_code, then booking.asmx in a webservice folder,

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Booking : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string SaveIt(string Email)
    {
        try
        {

            return "success";
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

}

javascript:

```
$("#email_popup_submit").click(function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/webservice/Booking.asmx/SaveIt',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'Email': 'testemail' },
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data.d);
            if (data.d == "success") {

                e.preventDefault();
                // console.log('SUCCESS!');

            } else {

            }
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
        }
    });
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment following line from your `service code` to be `enabled` to call from `javascript/ajax`

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to change data parameter to this:

```
data: '{ "Email":"testemail"}'
```